# Убрать горизонтальный scroll в tree primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Не получается убрать горизонтальный скрол.

```
<p:column >
    <p:panel style="widget:530px; height:230px; overflow: auto; display: block; ">  
       <p:tree value="#{sB.root}" var="orgtree" selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{sB.selectedNodes}" style="margin = 10px; ">
       <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{sB.refreshDuties}"
                                    update=":fltfrm:hposition :fltfrm:hperson :fltfrm:duty :fltfrm:category :fltfrm:group :fltfrm:position :fltfrm:person :datfrm" />
        <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{sB.refreshDuties}"
                                    update=":fltfrm:hposition :fltfrm:hperson :fltfrm:duty :fltfrm:category :fltfrm:group :fltfrm:position :fltfrm:person :datfrm" />
        <p:treeNode  >
            <h:outputText value="#{orgtree.caption}" style="white-space:pre-wrap;  word-wrap: break-word; "/>
        </p:treeNode >
    </p:tree>
</p:panel>
</p:column>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: overflow: auto; замени на overflow: hidden; либо добавь его в style для p:tree

Comment: Не помогает (((